# Different results for pow on x86 and x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am wondering why I am observering different results when using `pow` on x86 and x64 respectively. In our application we control the floating point rounding mode, which has worked fine on both Windows and Linux 32 bit.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cfloat>

void checkEqual(double expected, double observed) {   
    if (expected == observed) {
        printf("Expected %.23f, got %.23f\n", expected, observed);
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR: Expected %.23f, got %.23f\n", expected, observed);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {   
    unsigned ret, tmp;
    _controlfp_s(&ret, 0, 0);
    _controlfp_s(&tmp, RC_DOWN, MCW_RC);

    checkEqual(2048.0, pow(2.0, 11.0));
    checkEqual(0.125, pow(2.0, -3.0));

    return 0;   
}
```

Compiling and running with Visual Studio 2015 (2012 gives the same result) gives me the following output

x86:

```
Expected 2048.00000000000000000000000, got 2048.00000000000000000000000
Expected 0.12500000000000000000000, got 0.12500000000000000000000
```

x64:

```
ERROR: Expected 2048.00000000000000000000000, got  2047.99999999999977262632456
ERROR: Expected 0.12500000000000000000000, got 0.12499999999999998612221
```

Can anyone explain the differences? I know that inherently, floating point calculations are not exact, but for these specific values, I would expect the function to produce the same result regardless of rounding mode.

---

I investigated this some more and found that the real issue is not how `pow` is implemented but rather that x86 and x64 hardware are different as Hans Passant suggested.

Comment: Try compiling with the /arch:SSE2 flag to force SSE2 mode

Comment: BTW, 23 digits is 7 digits more than the maximum representable length with a 64-bit `double`. The rest of the digits are garbage.

Comment: That is entirely normal.  The x86 version uses FPU instructions that calculate with an  internal 80-bit format.  The x64 version uses SSE2 instructions.  Which does not increase the internal precision, thus producing much more consistent results.  But less accurate.  You still get a *correct* result, accurate to 15 significant digits which is all you can ever hope for with double precision math.  The rounding hack is not useful, it just causes a less precise result that on average doubles the calculation error for every floating point operation.

Comment: @SvenNilsson on x86 this did indeed force the `__libm_sse2_pow_precise` to be used, but(!) the results are still the same.

Comment: If you are specifically interested in `pow(2.0, n)` then use the `ldexp` function.

Comment: Then I suspect that the 32bit and 64bit FP libs are simply different, or that the CPU flags that control the rounding mode for some reason differs between the two target architectures. You are aware that the SSE and X87 use different flags for rounding mode?

Comment: @HansPassant the "rounding hack" is used in other aspects of our application - where it works as expected. But it is interesting that there is such a difference between the FPU and the SSE2 instruction. The results that I get corresponds to that 1 LSB has been subtracted from the mantissa.

Comment: @RaymondChen I need the exponent to be of type double. Otherwise a good suggestion.

Comment: @HansPassant you were absolutely correct. Its the "missing" precision on x64 that causes the difference in results.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different implementations of `pow` possible. For instance, `pow(x,y)` is `exp(y*ln(x))`. As you can imagine, `exp(11.0*ln(2.0))` can suffer from internal rounding errors even though `x` and `y` are exactly representable.

However, it's quite common to call `pow` with integer arguments, and therefore some libraries have optimized paths for those cases. E.g., `pow(x,2*n)` is `pow(x,n)` squared, and `pow(x, 2n+1)` is `x*pow(x, 2n)`.

It seems your x86 and x64 implementations differ in this respect. That can happen. IEEE only promises precise results for +-*/ and sqrt.